# How do I make this game stop as soon as a player makes a 2x2 grid with their number on a 5x5 grid

Tags: python

basically I've got this game and these are the rules:

-2 players;

-player 1 chooses a number from the 5x5 grid (matrix) to replace the 0 for 1 and then player 2 does the same (they take it in turns);

My problem is how do I make it stop when a player makes a 2x2 grid with their number (example) or every number 0 has been replaced by a 1 or a 2 (that makes it a draw):

```
            0 0 0 0 0
            0 1 1 2 0
            0 1 1 0 0
            0 0 0 2 0
            0 0 0 0 2
```

PLAYER 1 WINS

---

My code:

```
grid= [[0 for row in range (5)] for col in range (5)]

for i in range (0,10): (THIS IS THE PART THAT I NEED TO REPLACE)

player1_row = int (input ("Player 1, please enter the number of the row (0-4): "))
player1_col = int (input ("Player 1, please enter the number of the column (0-4): "))

grid [player1_row][player1_col]= 1

for s in grid:

    print(*s)

player2_row = int (input ("Player 2, please enter the number of the row (0-4): "))

player2_col = int (input ("Player 2, please enter the number of the column (0-4): "))

grid [player2_row][player2_col]= 2

for s in grid:

    print(*s)
```

---

This is my code so far:

```
            def check_for_win(grid):
                for x in range(4):
                    for y in range(4):
                        rect = (grid[x][y], grid[x+1][y], grid[x][y+1], grid[x+1][y+1])
                        if 0 not in rect and 1 not in rect:
                            # player 2 won
                            return 2
                        if 0 not in rect and 2 not in rect:
                            # player 1 won
                            return 1
                return None

            def check_finished(grid):
                for row in grid:
                    if 0 in row:
                        return False
                return True

            grid= [[0 for row in range (5)] for col in range (5)]
            for i in range (0,50):
                player1_row = int (input ("Player 1, please enter the number of the row (0-4): "))
                player1_col = int (input ("Player 1, please enter the number of the column (0-4): "))
                grid [player1_row][player1_col]= 1
                for s in grid:
                    print(*s)
                player2_row = int (input ("Player 2, please enter the number of the row (0-4): "))
                player2_col = int (input ("Player 2, please enter the number of the column (0-4): "))
                grid [player2_row][player2_col]= 2
                for s in grid:
                    print(*s)

                check_for_win(grid)
                check_finished(grid)
```

And this is the output: (It should stop and say that player one won)

```
            Player 1, please enter the number of the row (0-4): 1
            Player 1, please enter the number of the column (0-4): 1
            1 1 0 0 0
            1 1 0 0 0
            0 0 2 0 0
            0 0 0 0 2
            0 0 0 0 2
            Player 2, please enter the number of the row (0-4):
```

What should I do?

Comment: at least check for remaining zeros is simply `0 in grid`...

Comment: but I need to check first if there's a winner... how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that checks whether one of the players won like this:

```
def check_for_win(grid):
    for x in range(4):
        for y in range(4):
            rect = (grid[x][y], grid[x+1][y], grid[x][y+1], grid[x+1][y+1])
            if 0 not in rect and 1 not in rect:
                # player 2 won
                return 2
            if 0 not in rect and 2 not in rect:
                # player 1 won
                return 1
    return None
```

This function returns `1` if player 1 won, `2` if player 2 won and `None` otherwise.

Checking whether the game is finished is pretty easy:

```
def check_finished(grid):
    for row in grid:
        if 0 in row:
            return False
    return True
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be using a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

def check_for_win(grid):
    grid = np.array(grid)
    for i in range(grid.shape[0] - 1):
        for k in range(grid.shape[1] - 1):
            check = grid[i, k]
            if check != 0:
                if (grid[i:i+2, k:k+2] - check == 0).all():
                    return check
    if not 0 in grid:
        return -1
    return 0
```

This function iterates through the grid from upper left corner, so does not detect errornous boards where both players have a win pattern, but the frist winner is detected and the according number is returned.
It has the following return values:

- `1`, `2`: game won by player 1, 2
- `0` nothing happened
- `-1` game over with draw

---

Version with plain python, so grid is list of lists:

```
def check_for_win(grid):
    for i in range(len(grid[0]) - 1):
        for k in range(len(grid) - 1):
            check = grid[i][k]
            if check != 0:
                if all([elmnt == check for line in grid[k:k+2] for elmnt in line[i:i+2]]):
                    return check
    if not 0 in grid:
        return -1
    return 0
```

---

Test (using the numpy version):

```
np.random.seed(42)
grid = np.random.randint(0, 3, [5, 5])

array([[2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

check_for_win(grid)
Out: 1

grid[3, 2] = grid[1, 0] = 2

array([[2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

check_for_win(grid)
Out: 2


np.random.seed(1)
grid = np.random.randint(0, 3, [5, 5])

array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 2, 2]])

check_for_win(grid)
Out: 0


np.random.seed(8)
grid = np.random.randint(1, 3, [5, 5])

array([[2, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]])

check_for_win(grid)
Out: -1
```

Comment: where do I put the function?

Comment: What? lol It's your game - you explained it to me... But seriously: I think you should put it right after every move of any player, as it returns the state of the board (- but does not validate a board with unknown history).

Comment: I've done it and it gives me an error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Correct, sorry. I completely forgot to mention that this approach uses a numpy array as grid. So either do this also in your code and make grid already be a numpy array, or you can make the function cast the input list of lists into a numpy array (as in my edit)

Comment: It shows this:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

what do I do? Btw thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: Well, then numpy is not installed on your system. Try to use a python distribution where it's already shipped or you would have to install it by yourself. Numpy is the abbreviation for numerical python and it has its advantages over lists e.g. regarding indexing and mathematical calculations.

Comment: Can I do it without numpy?